# How to properly link SCSS using PythonAnywhere?

Tags: python, django, sass, pythonanywhere

I am currently working on revamping my portfolio, so I decided to switch fully to SCSS instead of CSS. Now even before when I commit from PyCharm I always need to edit it a little bit, to make it work in PythonAnywhere. The explanation:

This is the code I use to make it work in PyCharm

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Now to make this work in PythonAnywhere I have to edit above code to this:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['portfolio/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

MEDIA_ROOT = u'/home/Gromis/portfolio/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = u'/home/Gromis/portfolio/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I think that is the issue why I can't properly link SCSS file, is because of the wrong path in settings.py . I get this error now while loading the website:
`Unable to locate file scss/style.scss while rendering tag 'sass_src' in template project_index.html`
Of course, the same code works perfectly in PyCharm, so how should I edit these lines to make everything work in PythonAnywhere?

```py
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
]
# SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

This is the code where I load scss

```py
{% load sass_tags %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% sass_src 'scss/style.scss' %}" type="text/css"/>
```

This is the project tree

```sh
portfolio
├── README.md
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── media
├── myportfolio
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── portfolio
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── admin
│   ├── brand.png
│   ├── myportfolio
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── style.css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   │       └── main.js
│   ├── project3.png
│   ├── scss
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   ├── style.css.map
│   │   └── style.scss
│   └── swiper
│       └── swiper.js
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── project_detail.html
    └── project_index.html
```

Comment: My guess is that the difference is that the working directory is different  on PythonAnywhere vs running it in PyCharm.  All of the "os.path.join" stuff is meant to be there to handle that, though -- you shouldn't need to change your settings.py to run on PythonAnywhere.  What happens if you uncomment the line SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')?

Comment: @GilesThomas I was thinking the same, however, it does not work. The error stays the same:

`django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unable to locate file scss/style.scss while rendering tag 'sass_src' in template project_index.html`

This is directly from pythonanywhere error log file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Index.html you should have the CSS file loading in the browser instead of the SCSS file.

The Sass file compiles to your CSS file and then you need to link your CSS file.

So I guess that maybe this needs to change to as an example:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”{% static ‘css/styles.css’ %}”>
```

I use Pythonanywhere also, but with Flask, Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had to delete the old two lines:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/myportfolio/css/style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% sass_src 'scss/style.scss' %}" type="text/css"/>
```
To this:
```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'scss/style.css' %}">
``` For whatever reason, in PyCharm you can call the scss file, however, when you move to PythonAnywhere you need to call the css file, which is automatically generated from scss file, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

> The browsers currently don’t have direct support for Sass/SCSS or any
> other CSS pre-processor. All Sass/SCSS code compiles back to standard
> CSS so the browser can actually understand and render the results.
>
> [Reference](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-complete-guide-to-scss-sass-30053c266b23)

So, you should use a `CSS` file instead of the `SCSS` file.

You can use [node-sass package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) to compile your SCSS code to standardized CSS code so the browser can actually recognize.